# ViewModelScope launch doesn't work with onClick from Compose Layout

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm starting to use Jetpack Compose more in depth in my project. Right now I've a button like this one:

```
OutlinedButton(
            onClick = requestRightButtonClick,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(50),
            etc.
        ) {
            Text(etc.)
        }
```

The requestRightButtonClick is a function that does only this:

```
viewModel::saveSettings
```

And the viewModel function is something like this:

```
    fun saveSettings() = viewModelScope.launch {
        val robot = robotRepository.getRobot()
        settingsService.setData(
            robot.vendor,
            robot.serial,
            isSettingsOk.value
        )
        events.emit(SettingsSaved)
    }
```

Everything works fine with the first invocation. However, from the second click to this button, the saveSettings function is being called but what is inside the "launch" block, is never been executed. Any idea of the reason why this is happening?

Comment: can u please check, if viewModel's `onCleared` is called between first and second `saveSettings` method invocation is called?

Comment: yes indeed! :) please note also that the viewModel is defined as a singleton since it's shared with the previous fragment. How would I avoid this?

Comment: Yeah! I've configured the viewModel instance in a bad way. Using the proper sharedViewModel did the job. If you want to create an answer, I will accept it :) thank you a lot!

Comment: no need in it, I just recommended u the way, it's your solution)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else will end up in this page, the issue was to properly use sharedViewModel instead of using single to define a shared ViewModel.

So basically replace this code:

```
private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModel()
```

with:

```
private val viewModel: MyViewModel by sharedViewModel()
```

And, if you are using Koin, use this:

```
viewModel { MyViewModel() }
```

instead of:

```
single { MyViewModel() }
```

Special thanks to Sergei for give me the idea of solve this issue :)